# Receiving a "Insuffcient Privileges" Error on a Admin account in Dev edition?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Currently trying to build a piece of Visualforce and apex code to display every field from an object as an input field, so that it can be saved as a pre-gened form.

I am required to redact part of the JS Code, but it should be sufficient to say that all it is doing is running analytic information on the form.

Whenever I try to use the showFields() function I receive the Insufficient Priviledges error.

VS:

```
<apex:page controller="ObjectFormGenerator">

<script language="javascript">

/* jQuery */
document.write("<script type=\"text/JavaScript\" src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js\">");
document.write("</"+"script>"); 


document.write("<script type=\"text/JavaScript\" src=\"[ACTUAL URL REDACTED TO COMPLY WITH NDA]");
document.write("</"+"script>"); 

setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        [Session Code Redacted to comply with NDA] 
    });
},250);
</script>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectNames}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:commandButton value="Generate Form" action="{!showFields}"/>
            <br />

            <apex:repeat value="{!allFields}" var="field">
                <apex:inputField html-data-fieldname="{!field}" value="{!selectedSObject[field]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:page>
```

APEX:

```
public class ObjectFormGenerator {

    public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    public List <SelectOption> objectNames{public get; private set;}
    public String selectedObject {get; set;}

    public List<String> allFields {get;set;}

    public Schema.SObjectType selectedSObject {get;set;}

    // Intialize objectNames and fields

    public ObjectFormGenerator() {
        objectNames = initObjNames();
    }
    // Populate SelectOption list -

    // find all sObjects available in the organization

    private List<SelectOption> initObjNames() {
        List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<String> entities = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
        entities.sort();
        for(String name : entities)
        objNames.add(new SelectOption(name,name));

        return objNames;
    }

    // Find the fields for the selected object

    public void getFields() {
        //fields.clear();

        selectedSObject = schemaMap.get(selectedObject);

        allFields = new List<String>();

    }
    public PageReference showFields(){

        getFields();

        system.debug('$$$$$' + selectedObject);

        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values())
            {
                schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();

                system.debug('#######' + dfield );

                allFields.add(dfield.getname());
            }

         return null;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check with following URL, might be helpful for you

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005189

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?language=en_US&id=000004248

Comment: I had checked all that and was unable to find any permissions that the  Admin account did not have. Especially since it's the only account in use on this Developer Edition Org.

Comment: I think you are running this vf page through sites or community. Please check the permission for that profile).

Comment: I am not, I am running it from the main salesforce site.